# Saving all GET/page requests to database in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm looking for a way to integrate my own kind of "Google Analytics" logging into my Blazor application. What I would normally do if this was a .NET Core application, is that I would write some JavaScript that calls a controller endpoint, which then adds it to the database at some point. If I do that, the application won't halt or wait for the database request, because the frontend sent the call.

I'm not sure how I would do that in Blazor. I've looked at overriding the OnAfterRender method:

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        
    }
}
```

And then placed that in my MainLayout.razor file. That could work, however, `firstRender` is only true if I refresh the page (F5). OnAfterRender gets called every time, but on a single page load, I've seen it hit it a couple of times in the same page render.

Say I want to log every request - how would I go about that? I don't want the page load to wait for the database request, because that could easily be done in the background. If anything, adding every "request model" to a static/singleton list, which gets saved to the database every x seconds.

Comment: Override OnAfterRenderAsync instead and use a task to send the data on first render. If you need this for every page, create something like a `ExternalLoggingComponentBase` that inherits `ComponentBase` and have any page inherit `ExternalLoggingComponentBase` that you want to log with. 

If you have high throughput, you'll definitely want to batch this with some sort of in-memory cache that dumps every x seconds via a background service that won't be interrupted.

Comment: @BenSampica I need to look into inheritance from ComponentBase. Seems like that's the way to go indeed. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an Analytics service

```
    public class AnalyticsService
    {
        private string _currentUrl = string.Empty;

        public void PostURL(string url)
        {
            if (!this._currentUrl.Equals(url))
            {
                _currentUrl = url;
                PostToAnalytics();
            }
        }

        private async void PostToAnalytics()
        {
            //  use httpClient to post data
            // await HttpClient.PostAsync()
            // emulated post
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Analytics - {_currentUrl}");
        }
    }
```

Register it as Scoped in the Services Container.

Create an `AnalyticsControl` component.

```
    public class AnalyticsControl : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject] private AnalyticsService analyticsService { get; set; }

        [Inject] private NavigationManager navManager { get; set; }

        protected override void OnParametersSet()
        {
            this.analyticsService.PostURL(navManager.Uri);
            base.OnParametersSet();
        }
    }
```

Update "MainLayout" and any other layouts.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<AnalyticsControl Counter="counter"/>

@code {

    int counter = 0;

        protected override void OnParametersSet()
        {
        counter++;
        }
}
```

The incrementing counter is just a mechanism to force a `SetParametersAsync` cycle on the `AnalyticsControl`.  At the moment it just yields with a delay and logs the event to the output.  You should use the `HttpClient` to post whatever data you want to to the controller.

Comment: Neat - the OnParametersSet is pretty cool. I need to look into inheritance from ComponentBase and LayoutComponentBase. Thanks!